# Alternative initiating values for $\theta^{(0)}$ such that perceptron producs a different linear classifier

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

The following dataset is linearly separable with $\theta=[-0.5,-2]$ given the initiating $\theta^{(0)}=[0,0]$ for a perceptron algorithm:
$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i & \text{Data point $x^{(i)}$} & \text{Labels $y^{(i)}$}\\
\hline
1 & [1,-1] & 1 \\
2 & [0,1] & -1 \\
3 & [-1.5,-1] & 1
\end{array}
$$

It is then mentioned that if the initiating $\theta^{(0)}=[1000,-1000]$, corrections to $\theta$ have a smaller impact, thus requiring more corrections before we have a linear classifier.

I am then asked to provide a value of initiating $\theta^{(0)}$ so that the algorithm will return a different classifier than using  $\theta^{(0)}=[0,0]$.

I couldn't figure it out so I tried $\theta^{(0)}=[-1000,-1000]$, strangely it worked (although the solution provided is $\theta^{(0)}=[1,-2]$).

Why would $\theta^{(0)}=[-1000,-1000]$ or $\theta^{(0)}=[1,-2]$ yield a different result? I understand that there are always infinitely many linear classifiers possible (given it is linearly separable), since multiples of $\theta=[-0.5,-2]$ would also work, e.g. $\theta=[-1,-4]$.

What I don't get is why would having different $\theta^{(0)}$ make a difference, specifically these two?

Comment: You don't say which algorithm you're using, but it would seem that these are different minima and based on the objective function value, they may be both local or both global (in the sense that they both achieve the minimum possible objective function value) or one local and another global. So the starting point affects the solution trajectory of the algorithm.

Comment: @Hikaru Sorry, forgot to say that this is a Perceptron algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\{(0,1)\}$ in the negative class and $\{(1,-1), (-1.5, -1)\}$ is the positive class.

An easy way to set the initial $\theta^{(0)}$ such that it ends at a different classifier is to intentionally avoiding $(-0,5, -2)$ and yet pick  it such that it can separate the two classes. If we start with a vector that can separate the two classes then we are done.

In fact, you can pick any $\theta_1, \theta_2$ satisfying
$$(0,1)\cdot (\theta_1, \theta_2) < 0$$

$$(1,-1)\cdot (\theta_1, \theta_2) > 0$$
$$(-1.5,-1)\cdot (\theta_1, \theta_2) > 0$$

Notice that we can pick it to be $(1,-2)$.

Note, if you pick a different starting point, it is very unlikely that you end up with the same point.

Comment: I think I understand everything you said above, but I am afraid I still don't understand why would we end up with a different classifier $\theta$ if we pick a different starting $\theta^{(0)}$...?

Comment: I don't have a proof of that, it's just my intuitive feeling that there are so many points that we can converge to and each time we make a mistake, we swing it to make a correction according to the learning rate and we converges whenever we stop making any mistake.